# Comparing datetime.now().date() with a date constant in Python

Tags: date, datetime, python-3.x

Printing `datetime.now().date()` in Python 3 gives something like 2015-09-29.
However, when I want to compare `datetime.now().date()` to this constant, it does not work. I tried the following code snippets

```
import datetime
if datetime.now().date() == 2015-09-29:
    print('Hello')
```

This results in a syntax error: *Invalid token*.

```
import datetime
if datetime.now().date() == '2015-09-29':
    print('Hello')
```

This results in no error, but (when running this code on the 29th of September 2015), it does not print *Hello* either

```
import datetime
if datetime.now().date() == datetime.date(2015,9,29):
    print('Hello')
```

This results in an error: *descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'.*

Can anyone help me on this rather simple question, please? Thanks!

Comment: It is `datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code actually gives me a different error:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> if datetime.now().date() == datetime.date(2015,9,29):
...     print("hello")
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

`now` isn't a method of the datetime module, it's a method of the datetime.datetime class. Yes, it's confusing.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> if datetime.datetime.now().date() == datetime.date(2015,9,29):
...     print('Hello')
...
Hello
```

---

Alternatively, I can get the error message you did, but only if I tweak the `import` statement:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> if datetime.now().date() == datetime.date(2015,9,29):
...     print('Hello')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

But you can't create a `date` object this way, because you imported only the `datetime` class. Try importing both.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> if datetime.now().date() == date(2015,9,29):
...     print('Hello')
...
Hello
```

Comment: You can replace `datetime.now().date()` with `date.today()` in the later case